# Deserialization exception : Unable to find assembly

Tags: c#, .net, deserialization, serializable

I work on winforms project.

I try to deserialize an object:

```
private void CreateObjects()
        {
            try
            {
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("path to file", FileMode.Open))              
                   sObjects = (Objects)(new BinaryFormatter().Deserialize(fs)); 
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

But in this row:

```
sObjects = (Objects)(new BinaryFormatter().Deserialize(fs));
```

I get this exception:

**Unable to find assembly 'TheNameOfTheClass, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.**

Any idea what may cause this exception?

Comment: Do you have that assembly in place?

Comment: Can you instantiate manually 'TheNameOfTheClass' from this section of code?

Answer (score 0):

If your class con taint object that do not have the Serializeable tag, you can't Deserialize them. You will need to mark these object with the NonSerializable tag.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nonserializedattribute.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If in your AssemblyInfo.cs version defined like this:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.*.*")]
```

Then change it to this:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```